# Forward kolmogrov differential difference equation

Tags: differential-forms

While reading research papers related to Queueing models, 
 without solving the equation, authors have plotted graph for kolmogrov forward differential difference equation using  matlab.How it's possible?

Comment: [Isn't it just finite differencing a system of ODEs or a single PDE?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_equations_(Markov_jump_process)#Relation_with_the_generating_function)

Comment: Finite system of equations

Comment: Why don't you give us the paper so everyone can see what the author has done.